# Geometry Nodes - Mapping a curve tangent to nearest vertices

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm having a bit of a headache with this one, I have a bezier on a plane and I'm trying to map the tangent of each point on the nearest geometry of the plane with geo nodes.

I have a Sample Curve node that outputs the curve tangent information, with the Factor controlling where to sample the info along the curve.

[image: Sample Curve controlling the tangent information]

But I can't figure out how to map on the plane, the nearest tangent value of the curve. I've tried messing around with Sample Nearest, Geometry Proximity, but I have no clue what to do next. So if you refer to the image above, I want to see a gradient from yellow to the left of the curve, to red at the opposite end of the curve. I need it to work no matter the complexity of the curve (It's to make a flowmap of rivers and stuff like that)

Any clues ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Blender version : 3.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work like this:

[image]

Tricky part that sample nearest doesn't work with curves, so you have to convert it to mesh

Comment: Is this node mini-map at the bottom a new feature or an add-on?

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much I was going crazy with this haha, it's exactly what I need. Now I can drive my flow map with the curve tangent.

Comment: @Blunder this is an add-on: https://github.com/strike-digital/node_minimap